# Is there a way to see all upcoming daily login rewards for Injustice on iOS?

Tags: ios, android, injustice-gods-among-us

Is it possible to view all the upcoming login rewards for Injustice: Gods Among Us on iOS? I can only see a few after I login, which makes it hard to know how many daily logins I have left to something actually useful and plan ahead on my character development. I searched for a list somewhere but couldn't find any, so one would be useful, too.